# Java and R: Least Squares Coefficient Estimation - Start at time Zero?

Tags: r, least-squares, java, regression-coefficients

This is the data set I have:

```
vector <- c( -7.459981, 13.26651, 12.10128, 2.380662, 26.42393)
```

Doing an estimation of the coefficient with a linear regression in Java and R I got different results. This is my code in Java.

```
List<Double> y= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
        -7.4599812, 13.2665113, 12.1012781, 2.3806622, 26.4239262
        ));
SimpleRegression ls = new SimpleRegression();
List<Double> yNew = new ArrayList<Double>();
for (int i = 0; i < y.size(); i++) {
    ls.addData(i, y.get(i));
}

double alpha0 = ls.getIntercept();
double beta0 = ls.getSlope();
double coefficients[] = { alpha0, beta0 };
```

This is the output result:

```
alpha0 = -2.0339138199999995
beta0  =  5.68819657
```

In R it seems to be that we should start for x with 1 instead of 0:

> lsfit(x, y, wt = NULL, intercept = TRUE, tolerance = 1e-07, yname =
>   NULL)

Starting with 1 instead of 0 in R, I get:

```
vector <- c( -7.459981, 13.26651, 12.10128, 2.380662, 26.42393)
vecx <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
lsfit(vecx, vector)
alpha = -7.72211 
beta = 5.688197
```

When I start with 0 in R, I get:

```
vector <- c( -7.459981, 13.26651, 12.10128, 2.380662, 26.42393)
vecx <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
lsfit(vecx, vector)
alpha = -2.033915  
beta = 5.688197
```

which is the same value as my code in Java. On the internet I have found that the values of my Java code and with vecx <- c(0,1,2,3,4) in R are the values which are correct but I am not sure.

**My question is: What is the truth? To start with 0 or with 1 to estimate the coefficients?**

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: If you are going to regress the data against an index, your choice of starting value (and increment) is perfectly arbitrary.  This is not an issue of "truth" but only of making sure you understand what your software is doing.

Comment: I can see your point but I am not convinced yet. Surely I do want to regress my data against an index because I am dealing with time series. That's why I asked if the starting index should be 0 or 1 as the estimation of the regression coefficients are different.

Comment: You do not need to be convinced: you need to tell us what the times are. If you want to call them 0, 1, 2, 3, ... or 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., or 1/1/2015, 1/2/2015, 1/3/2015, etc., is entirely up to you.  You simply haven't supplied any information concerning that aspect of your model, so there's no question here that we can answer.

Comment: I am using times 01/2014, 02/2014, 03/2014 etc.

Comment: Not in your examples!  If those are your intended times, then they are what you must provide for `vecx` in your code.

Comment: Oh, that's a point... As I have no idea how to do that, is there any documentation how I can provide date times such as mine into vecx and thus lsfit?

Comment: See the `R` documentation on the "date" class.  You can start exploring those docs by typing `? date` at the `R` command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intercept in a linear model is the value of the dependent variable that the model expects when all your independent variables are equal to 0.  So if you redefine an independent variable in such as way as to change where 0 is - in this case by adding or subtracting one - then you will (except in degenerate cases) change the model's estimate of what value the dependent variable is expected to take there.

This is exactly what you would want to happen.

Since you are apparently dealing with dates, consider the various coding choices.  You could decide to work with these dates in Julian days or in days since February 2 2010.  The corresponding intercept estimates would the expected values of the dependent variable on January 1, 4713 BC and on February 2 2010 respectively, but the slope coefficients would be the same.

Alternatively you could operate in *months* since February 2010.  Then your intercept would be the expected value of the dependent variable on that date but the new slope coefficient would be approximately 1/30 of the size that it was when you used days.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @conjugateprior! I am going to model these dates with time periods. What I mean is the following: For instance, the start date 01/2010 becomes t_1=1, 02/2012 becomes t_2 = 2 and so on. I guess this is much simpler to handle.